# How to set response language in PayPal REST API?

Tags: rest, paypal

[Disclaimer: I am not sure if PayPal supports this]

Hello,

I am trying to get the response to PayPal REST API calls in a specific language.
For instance, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture always returns a response in English. What if I'd like to have a response in Spanish?

ChatGPT suggested to use the "Accept-Language" header with codes like "it_IT", but no luck!

I also tried to set the `payment_source` and the `locale` option within it, but no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to change the response language of API calls. They will always be in English (US).

To show site messages in a different language, have your code look at the `error` + `issue` of the responses only (all capital letters with underscores) and, based on these identifiers, show the message/description of your choice for the situation, in the desired language.

Orders API errors [are documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/orders/v2/errors/)

Comment: Ok, so as I expected there is no way you can get the translation from PayPal, you'd have to implement it yourself.